# .net core application error after deploying to azure-Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-kontent

Please assist my application is working local and breaks after deploying to azure.

```
<li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul></fieldset></div>
```

##### Detailed Error Information:

Module   AspNetCoreModuleV2Notification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   aspNetCoreError Code   0x00000000
Requested URL   http://kenticobetwaydev:80/Physical Path   C:\home\site\wwwrootLogon Method   AnonymousLogon User   Anonymous

##### More Information:

This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393)

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

Comment: this will help you-https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13718

Comment: there are several other threads with this error on SO, have you tried any of the other suggestions yet?

Answer (score -1):

I needed to add webconfig on my project before deploying it to azure

Comment: You must clearly specify which content that you have added in to webconfig , in order to resolved above issue. Thanks